# declaration/definition and instantiation of COM objects with visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, declaration, objectinstantiation

i need to instantiate com object which is .dll and on local machine in visual c++,i know that it can be done by using CoCreateInstance("clsid") ,but i am confused about declaration.so can anyone explain all steps involved?
for late binding as well as early binding

1. is any import/inclusion required
2. how to declare com object ?
3. any other steps required before createinstance (e.g CoInitialize?)

or provide any specific reference involving step by step code

Comment: thanks LihO and Seva  both of your answers are really helpful, both shows two different ways, #import is more efficient but i can't find typelib of one of object,i am confused which answer i should accept as both are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to call `CoInitialize` and don't forget to call`CoUnitialize` if initialization was successful.

So your code will have the following structure:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL); 
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    try
    {
        CoCreateInstance(...)
        // ...
    }
    catch (_com_error &e)
    {
        //...
    }
    CoUninitialize();
}
```

For more information visit [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I recommend you to start with [The COM Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then you should read something about [CoInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [CoCreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions before you use them.

This tutorial could help you too: [Introduction to COM - What It Is and How to Use It](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633/Introduction-to-COM-What-It-Is-and-How-to-Use-It).

Comment: I remember the pair CoInitialize/CoUninitialize should be used, say, in main. If CoInitialize fails, there is little point in further process. Your answer suggests to call before each CoCreateInstance.

Comment: Yes, it is initialization of COM Library, that allows you to create instance of COM and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

1. `#import` is very much recommended. if you import the typelib with #import, you'll be using the Native COM framework, which isolates some gritty details and makes life generally easier.
2. In Native COM, something like this:

   LibName::IMyInterfacePtr pInterface;

In raw C++:

```
IMyInterface *pInterface;
```

But see above.

3. Call CoInitialize() in the beginning of the program, CoUninitialize() in the end. if running inside a DLL, then it's much more complicated.